# INNER JOIN or nested SELECT in this case?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, inner-join

I have two tables:

```
atvtrails_prim:

ID int PK
ID2 int
TType varchar(100)

atvtrails_sec:

ID2 int Foreign Key(Relates to ID2 of atvtrails_prim)
Latitude double
Longitude double
```

What I want from these tables: All the records in atvtrails_sec whose ID2 has a specific TType in atvtrails_prim.

Query I am using(Nested SELECT):

```
SELECT atvtrails_sec.ID2,atvtrails_sec.Latitude, atvtrails_sec.Longitude,atvtrails_prim.TType 
FROM atvtrails_sec,atvtrails_prim 
WHERE atvtrails_sec.Latitude BETWEEN %@ and %@ 
AND atvtrails_sec.Longitude BETWEEN %@ and %@ 
AND (
    SELECT TType from atvtrails_prim where ID2=atvtrails_sec.ID2
    ) =%@", lrLat, ulLat, lrLong, ulLong,type2
```

lrLat, ulLat, lrLong, ulLong,type2 are variables. I am coding in objective-c.

This query gives me a very large dataset. It does give me the correct ones but they are being duplicated. I get around 90000 results while the table has only 18000 records. This query is taking a lot of time when I measured and I want a faster solution.

Query I am using(INNER JOIN):

```
SELECT atvtrails_sec.ID2,atvtrails_sec.Latitude, atvtrails_sec.Longitude 
FROM atvtrails_sec 
INNER JOIN atvtrails_prim ON atvtrails_prim.TType=%@ 
WHERE atvtrails_sec.Latitude BETWEEN %@ and %@ 
AND atvtrails_sec.Longitude BETWEEN %@ and %@", lrLat, ulLat, lrLong, ulLong,type1
```

This is not returning me any data. I am new to SQLite. Kindly guide me as to how can I get the desired data using Inner-Join. Also, is there any way to optimize my nested SELECT query so that it doesn't give me extra data?

Comment: You can highlight code segments in your question and click the `{}` icon to preserve code formatting.   Also try to format the code in a readable way.  Finally, are you using mysql or sqlite? Delete the improper tag.

Comment: Having trouble parsing your queries, but it doesn't look like you're ever actually joining your tables together in your second query.  There are tons of tutorials out there, here's one: [Clicky](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: I am using SQLite here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work?:

```
SELECT prim.ID,sec.*
FROM atvtrails_prim prim
LEFT JOIN atvtrails_sec sec ON sec.ID2 = prim.ID2
WHERE prim.TType = 'dirt';
```

Also, you might want to index your atvtrails_prim.TType column for better query performance:

```
ALTER TABLE atvtrails_prim ADD KEY TType (TType );
```

Answer (score 1):

The results are getting bloated because you forget to apply the meaningful join clause. A join of two tables without a clause is called a Cartesian join and will return `t1 * t2` rows, where t1 is the number of rows in table1 and t2 the number of rows in t2.

With the meaningful join clause, in this case i mean the `t1.ID2 = t2.ID2` clause. If this is a foreign key relation, this clause ensures that the maximum number of rows returned is MAX(t1,t2).

So start your query like this, and take it from there:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.ID2 = t2.ID2
(...)
```

Comment: "A join of two tables without a clause is called a Cartesian join and will return t1 * t2 rows, where t1 is the number of rows in table1 and t2 the number of rows in t2." +1